# Django Admin - Many to Many Field - Display only selected options

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Basically, I have two models: collection and custom_object. The custom_object has some general fields (id, name, value) and could be anything. A collection is like a group of many custom objects, realized as ManyToManyField in Django.

E.g.; collection

- collection_id
- collection_name
- ...
- custom_objects = models.ManyToManyField(to=custom_object, related_name="related_co")

I want to inspect on the admin site some collections, mainly which custom_objects are selected.
The problem here is that I have more than 20k different custom_objects, which takes a while to load the page and then the next problem is to scroll all 20k entries down to find some selected custom_objects.
For each collection, only about 10-20 custom_objects are selected, and not so much.
I want to see only the selected options; it's not important for me to see or select one of the other 19,980 options because selection and deselection are done by cronjob.

It's just important to see selected custom_objects. Any idea how to do this e.g. in admin.py for the collection model class?

Thanks a lot for bringing in your expertise and knowledge!

I tried something like this:

```
class collection(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name', 'id']

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
            kwargs["queryset"] = collection.objects.filter( ??? ) ?
        return super(collection, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: you can make a method display_custom_objects() and make as read_only field, where you can show selected custom_objects and remove custom_objects field from Modelform.